# CSS: Getting Everything on One Side

Tags: css

Okay so i want the image and next to it i want the h1 and p! something like this

```
 --------
|        |
|        | h1 tag with name
| Image  | p tag with description
|        |
|        |
 --------

<img src="" style="position:relative;left:10px;"> <h1 >SOmething</h1>
<p>asdasdsa</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `float:left` css property on image and h1 elements. Then use p

OR

Create a table with two td

```
<table><tr><td>image</td><td>[H1] [P]</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do some thing like:

```
<img src="loading.gif" alt="Test image" style="float:left;"/><h1 style="float:left;">here</h1><p style="float:left;">abc</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<image src="source.png" alt="alt" id="theimage"/>
<div id="nameanddescription">
<h1>Name</h1>
<p>description</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#theimage
{
    float: left;
}

#nameanddescription
{
    float: left;
}
```